# Implementation of Comparable not sorting List

Tags: java, mongodb, list, sorting, comparator

I'm having trouble getting my objects to sort.

Some initial knowledge:
I'm using MongoDB to store my collection, I'm able to retrieve them and get everything back correctly.

I have a class that implements Comparable, with a compareTo function, but I also want to be able to sort on different properties, thus I've added static comparables for each property I want to sort on.

```
public class PlaceHolder implements Comparable<PlaceHolder>{

private String name;
private String icon;
private String originalLangcode;

//Getters and setters + constructors here, these work 100%.

@Override
public int compareTo(PlaceHolder ph) {
    return this.getName().compareTo(ph.getName());
}

public static Comparator<PlaceHolder> nameComparator = new Comparator<PlaceHolder>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PlaceHolder ph1, PlaceHolder ph2) {
        return ph1.getName().compareTo(ph2.getName());
    }
};

public static Comparator<PlaceHolder> iconComparator = new Comparator<PlaceHolder>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PlaceHolder ph1, PlaceHolder ph2) {
        return ph1.getIcon().compareTo(ph2.getIcon());
    }
};

public static Comparator<PlaceHolder> nativeLangComparator = new Comparator<PlaceHolder>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PlaceHolder ph1, PlaceHolder ph2) {
        return ph1.getNativeLang().compareTo(ph2.getNativeLang());
    }
};
}
```

I've then wrote a function that gets all placeholders from my mongodb, returning them in a list with PlaceHolder objects.

```
public List<PlaceHolder> getAllPlaceholders(String sortType) {
    List<PlaceHolder> list = getPlaceholderList();
    switch(sortType) {
    case "name":
        Collections.sort(list, PlaceHolder.nameComparator);
        break;
    case "icon":
        Collections.sort(list, PlaceHolder.iconComparator);
        break;
    case "native":
        Collections.sort(list, PlaceHolder.nativeLangComparator);
        break;
    default:
        Collections.sort(list, PlaceHolder.nameComparator);
        break;
    }

    return list;

}
```

I always get my data unsorted:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "56653f82972552a4024814a3"} , "name" : "testHolder" , "icon" : "archive" , "originalLangcode" : "ENG"}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5665427a97253f798067c57b"} , "name" : "doItHolder" , "icon" : "car" , "originalLangcode" : "ENG"}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "566545dd9725050a53b4a5a8"} , "name" : "testableHolder" , "icon" : "adjust" , "originalLangcode" : "ENG"}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5665479b972511264f55aae1"} , "name" : "dataHolder" , "icon" : "hdd-o" , "originalLangcode" : "ENG"}
```

I'm failing to see what goes wrong.
I've debugged the comparables, and they seem to work, returning negatives and positives. But the list just doesnt seem to get sorted.

I'm using getAllPlaceholders in my controller, passing it to my Page handler which in turn generates html for a table view.

```
public class PlaceHolderControllerF extends ControllerAbF {

@Autowired PlaceHolderRepo pr;

@RequestMapping(value = "placeholderlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String editLanguage(HttpSession httpSession) {
    if (getUser(httpSession) == null) {
        return noPermission();
    }
    return Pages.getPlaceHolderList(pr.getAllPlaceholders("name"));
}
```

Pages just gets my index html, passes some variables to it that then runs through my templater which fills in the variables into the html.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the `getAllPlaceholders` method?

Comment: a bit offtopic, if you are using a custom comperator even though, why did you implement the interface?

Comment: @Eran Added it in an edit.

Comment: @StefanCandan You are not passing a sort type in `pr.getAllPlaceholders()`. Is it a different method?

Comment: @Eran Added one, it got lost due to an attempt to fix it, but alas, no dice.

Comment: @StefanCandan And what does `Pages.getPlaceHolderList` do?

Comment: @Eran Pages just gets my index.html, passes it to the templater which then fills in the gaps and generates html for the collection to display it neatly in a table, but even before that, when I Systemout my data, it's still unsorted.

Comment: you also need to add `break` after the `native` case.

Comment: @StefanCandan which library you are using to make it json?

Comment: @sreejith [Google's GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: I also tried the same sample (without MongoDB). After adding break for native code it works fine. Can you try printing pr.getAllPlaceholders("name")?